# struct pointer as return type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to print `kk[i].data[j]` but it is not printing at all.

`intarr_save_binary` is returning 2. I expect to get 0.

`int k = sizeof(kk) / sizeof(kk[0]);` gives 0. I'm expecting to get 5.

Did I properly allocate the memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {

    int len;
    int *data;

}intarr_t;

#define MAX 5

intarr_t* intarr_create(unsigned int len) {

    intarr_t* new_intarr = (intarr_t*)malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));
    if (!new_intarr) return NULL;

    new_intarr->data = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    new_intarr->len = len;
    return new_intarr;

}
int intarr_save_binary(intarr_t* ia, const char* filename) {

    if (!ia) return 1;
    if (!ia->data) return 2;

    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!f) return 3;

    if (fwrite(&ia->len, sizeof(ia->len), 1, f) == 1) {
        fprintf(f, "%d ", ia->len);
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }

    if (fwrite(ia->data, sizeof(ia->data), ia->len, f) == ia->len) {
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        fclose(f);
        return 5;
    }
}
int main() {

    intarr_t *ia = (intarr_t*)malloc(MAX*sizeof(intarr_t));

    int i;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {

        ia[j].len = j + 1;

    }

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {

        ia[j].data = (int*)malloc(ia[j].len * sizeof(int));

    }

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < ia[j].len; i++) {

            ia[j].data = (i + 1) * j;

        }
    }

    char name[20] = "myfile.txt";
    int d;

    printf("%d \n", intarr_save_binary(ia, name));


    intarr_t *kk;
    kk = intarr_create(MAX);


    int k = sizeof(kk) / sizeof(kk[0]);
    printf("%d\n",k);

    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < kk[j].len; i++) {

            printf("%d: %d\n", i, kk[j].data[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(kk);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: kk is a pointer, not an array, so sizeof kk is the size of 1 pointer: 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(kk) / sizeof(kk[0]);` only works for arrays, it doesn't work for pointers. And there is no way to find out the total size of what is pointed to. You have to remember how much you allocated.

Comment: And this `ia[j].data = (i + 1) * j;` cannot possibly compile, as `data` is a pointer and the value assigned is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

> intarr_save_binary is returning 2. I expect to get 0.

```
for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < ia[j].len; i++) {

        ia[j].data = (i + 1) * j;

    }
}
```

This zeroes `ia[0].data` on the very first pass through the double loop. (`ia[0].data = (0 + 1) * 0` gives `0`).

Thus `ia->data` is `0`, and `!ia->data` is true, making the function `return 2`.

---

> int k = sizeof(kk) / sizeof(kk[0]); gives 0. I'm expecting to get 5.

You obviously expect `sizeof kk` to give the total amount of memory allocated for `kk`.

And that is what you get, actually -- the total amount of memory allocated for `intarr_t *`, which is the type of `kk` at that point. That most likely results in 4 or 8, depending on your architecture. What it is **not** is whatever `len * sizeof(int)` resulted in when you called `intarr_create()`. As @BoPersson commented, if you allocate the memory yourself, you have to remember yourself how much you allocated.

The `sizeof kk / sizeof kk[0]` "trick" only works if `kk` *actually is an array*, i.e. if it has been declared as such within the scope of you using the `sizeof` operator on it so the compiler can "see" its size.

So, as you have an `int` and an `int *` in your struct `kk[0]`, which together are very likely to require more memory than an `intarr_t *`, the integer division results in `0`.

---

You might also take note that `free()` is not recursive. With `free(kk)`, you are leaking all the memory you allocated for all the `data` members. For every `malloc()`, there needs to be a *corresponding* `free()`. (And it **does** matter even if the program ends right after that one `free()`, as not all operating systems can / will protect you from this error.)